# javafx using translatetransition and keyevent to move image around screen

Tags: javafx, transition, move, translate, keyevent

I am trying to make a simple tile based movement system so that when a direction is pressed a translate transition is played to smoothly move the character one tile over.  The problem I am running into is that when I play the animation the image does the transition fine but after the transition completes, the image jumps to a spot further than intended. If I take out the portion of code onFinished then the animation plays perfectly but pressing directions after that cause the image to move from the previous place not the current location.

Here is the code

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class ControlTranslateImage extends Application
{   
    final int STEP_SIZE = 64;
    final Duration DURATION = Duration.millis(500);
    Group player;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        final ImageView image0 = new ImageView(new Image("http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/slime_idle.gif"));


        player = new Group(image0);
        player.getChildren().setAll(image0);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(player, 900, 600, Color.WHITE);

        moveOnKeyPressed(scene, player);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void moveOnKeyPressed(Scene scene, Group player)
    {

        final TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(DURATION, player);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch(e.getCode())
            {

                case UP:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getLayoutX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getLayoutY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getLayoutX());
                    transition.setToY(player.getLayoutY() - STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.playFromStart();
                    transition.setOnFinished(t -> {
                        player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX());
                        player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() - STEP_SIZE);
                    });

                } break;
                case DOWN:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getLayoutX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getLayoutY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getLayoutX());
                    transition.setToY(player.getLayoutY() + STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.playFromStart();

                    transition.setOnFinished(t -> {
                        player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX());
                        player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY() + STEP_SIZE);
                    });

                } break;
                case LEFT:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getLayoutX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getLayoutY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getLayoutX() - STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.setToY(player.getLayoutY());
                    transition.playFromStart();

                    transition.setOnFinished(t -> {
                        player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() - STEP_SIZE);
                        player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY());
                    });
                    player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() - STEP_SIZE);
                    player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY());


                } break;
                case RIGHT:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getLayoutX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getLayoutY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getLayoutX() + STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.setToY(player.getLayoutY());
                    transition.playFromStart();

                    transition.setOnFinished(t -> {
                        player.setLayoutX(player.getLayoutX() + STEP_SIZE);
                        player.setLayoutY(player.getLayoutY());
                    });
                } break;

                default:break;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A [`TranslateTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) manipulates the `translateX` and `translateY` properties, not the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties.

Comment: Don't post your fixed code in your question, instead [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and paste the fixed code there.  After some time you may get enough reputation to mark your own answer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed code

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class ControlTranslateImage extends Application
{   
    final int STEP_SIZE = 64;
    final Duration DURATION = Duration.millis(500);
    Group player;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        final ImageView image0 = new ImageView(new Image("http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/slime_idle.gif"));

        player = new Group(image0);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(player, 900, 600, Color.WHITE);

        moveOnKeyPressed(scene, player);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void moveOnKeyPressed(Scene scene, Group player)
    {

        final TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(DURATION, player);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch(e.getCode())
            {

                case UP:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getTranslateX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getTranslateY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getTranslateX());
                    transition.setToY(player.getTranslateY() - STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.playFromStart();

                } break;
                case DOWN:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getTranslateX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getTranslateY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getTranslateX());
                    transition.setToY(player.getTranslateY() + STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.playFromStart();

                } break;
                case LEFT:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getTranslateX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getTranslateY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getTranslateX() - STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.setToY(player.getTranslateY());
                    transition.playFromStart();

                } break;
                case RIGHT:
                {

                    transition.setFromX(player.getTranslateX());
                    transition.setFromY(player.getTranslateY());
                    transition.setToX(player.getTranslateX() + STEP_SIZE);
                    transition.setToY(player.getTranslateY());
                    transition.playFromStart();

                } break;

                default:break;

            }
        });
    }
}
```